# Discrete axis labeling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I add discrete labels to axes in d3?

I'm trying to create a line chart with discrete X axis labels using d3 v4, but failed. The order of labels the line links doesn't follow the label I put on the graph at all.
[image]

Here are some codes for generating the graph.

```
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Carlton","Carlton North","Flemington","West Melbourne","Docklands","Kensington","North Melbourne","Melbourne","East Melbourne","Parkville","Port Melbourne"]).range([0, width/11,(2*width)/11,(3*width)/11,(4*width)/11,(5*width)/11,(6*width)/11,(7*width)/11,(8*width)/11,(9*width)/11,(10*width)/11,width]);
var y0 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var y1 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

And here is a part of the data set:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Docklands",
        "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.340",
        "TreeAmount": "6000",
        "WildlifeAmount": "13"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kensington",
        "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.439",
        "TreeAmount": "5000",
        "WildlifeAmount": "7"
    },
    {
        "Name": "North Melbourne",
        "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.466",
        "TreeAmount": "4000",
        "WildlifeAmount": "11"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Carlton",
        "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.1849",
        "TreeAmount": "9000",
        "WildlifeAmount": "10"
    }
]
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the domain of the ordinal scale is not enough. You have to **sort the data** according to the desired order (that is, the scale's domain).

For instance:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return x.domain().indexOf(a.Name) - x.domain().indexOf(b.Name);
});
```

After that, you can pass the data to the line generator.

Here is the demo:

```js
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Carlton", "Carlton North", "Flemington", "West Melbourne", "Docklands", "Kensington", "North Melbourne", "Melbourne", "East Melbourne", "Parkville", "Port Melbourne"]);

var data = [{
    "Name": "Docklands",
    "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.340",
    "TreeAmount": "6000",
    "WildlifeAmount": "13"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kensington",
    "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.439",
    "TreeAmount": "5000",
    "WildlifeAmount": "7"
  },
  {
    "Name": "North Melbourne",
    "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.466",
    "TreeAmount": "4000",
    "WildlifeAmount": "11"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Carlton",
    "ID": "ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e.1849",
    "TreeAmount": "9000",
    "WildlifeAmount": "10"
  }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return x.domain().indexOf(a.Name) - x.domain().indexOf(b.Name);
});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```